# Regex (.*) without matching the second case

Tags: regex

Given the following sample input text:

> {{A1|def|ghi|jkl}}hello world. {{A2|mno}}bye world.

How can I create a regex pattern to only matching the first instance of `{{ ... }}` (i.e. only `{{A1|def|ghi|jkl}}`).  `A1` and `A2` are fixed inputs and `def`, `ghi`, `jkl`, and `mno` could be anything.

I've tried this:

```
\{\{A1\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\}\}
```

But that returns everything (`{{A1|def|ghi|jkl}}hello world. {{A2|mno}}`).

Note that `def` or `ghi` or `jkl` or `mno` could be numbers, English letters or other languages (e.g. Chinese/Japanese/Korean).

Comment: Please specify which flavor of regex (i.e. which language or tool).  Sometimes it's not a big deal, but in this case, where look-arounds are the best solution, the difference between regex flavors matters a great deal.

Comment: @StevenDoggart: *"in this case, where look-arounds are the best solution"* : really?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Ha!  I actually hesitated to use the word *best*, knowing that it was a bit overly emphatic without more details and a loaded term, so I understand why you pointed that out.  I know the regex community on SO has a penchant for pedantry, but not as bad as the English.SE site, so I figured I'd get away with it.

Comment: @StevenDoggart: I said that because my first (and unique) idea is to only use character classes.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Nice!  Since more details from the OP do not seem to be forthcoming, go for it!  I'd be curious to see what you came up with.

Comment: Is it always 3 characters per section, always 3 sections pipe delimited?  Or is it N number of characters, and/or N number of sections?

Comment: @StevenDoggart: sorry, I was watching "who is the boss?" with Tony Danza and Judith Light. I will now post an answer. Oh crap, you have already written more and less the same thing.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Time well spent, I'm sure :)  As you can see from my answer, I was just initially confused by the question (or at least I think so).

Comment: @StevenDoggart: Yes, but note that this situation is a little bit similar, on a suspense point of view, to "who is the boss": "will Tony get married with Angela?" <=> "Is it a question about greediness?" . Perhaps the next season will give us the answer.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Unfortunately I'm not as well versed in my who's-the-boss knowledge as you are, so I'll just have to take you word on that.  I don't think I've seen an episode of that show since I was 10.  I have much clearer recollections of Small Wonder...

Answer (score 3):

It's a little unclear what you are trying to accomplish.  At first, I thought that your problem was just that you were getting the entire thing when all you really wanted was the `A1` or `A2` part.  If so, here's the answer:

---

Since you didn't specify which flavor of regex you are using, it's hard to say for sure.  If you are using a version which supports look-arounds, you could do something like this:

```
(?<={{)\w+(?=(\|[^|}]*)+}})
```

Here's the meaning of the pattern:

- `(?<={{)` - This is a positive look-behind expression which means that it asserts that any match must be preceded by certain characters.  In this case, the characters are `{{`.
- `\w+` - This is the actual part that we are matching.  In this case, it's one or more word characters.  `\w` is a special character class.  This varies, though, depending on which regex engine you are using.  Something like `[A-Z][0-9]` may be more appropriate, depending on your needs.
- `(?=(\|[^|}]*)+}})` - This is a positive look-ahead expression.  That means that it asserts that any match must be followed by some particular pattern of characters.  In this case, it's looking for matches to be followed by `(\|[^|}]*)+}}`.

However, if look-arounds are not possible, then you can match it with a capturing group, like this:

```
{{(\w+)(\|[^|}]*)+}}
```

If you do it that way, you'll need to read the value of the first group for each match.

As far as only finding the first match goes, that really depends on which tool or language you are using.  Most regex engines only find the first match by default and only find additional matches when a global modifier is specified (often `/g` at the end).

---

However, now, after having edited your question, and trying better to understand what you meant, I think that your real problem is greediness.  The repetitions, such as `*`, in regex are greedy by default.  That means they will capture as much text as they possibly can and still have it match.  In this case, you don't want it to find the longest possible match.  In this case, you want it to find the shortest possible match.  You could do that simply by making the repetitions lazy (i.e. non-greedy).  To do that, simply add a `?` after the `*`.  For instance:

```
\{\{A1\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\}\}
```

However, that's not very efficient.  If this pattern is going to be used often or on large inputs it would be better to use a more restrictive character class, such as `[^}|]` instead of `.`, so that the lazy modifier is unnecessary.  For example:

```
\{\{A1\|([^}|]*)\|([^}|]*)\|([^}|]*)\}\}
```

Or, more simply:

```
{{A1(\|([^}|]*)){3}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your pattern is simply that you've made all of the `*` quantifiers greedy.  They're matching as much of the string as they can (while still allowing the whole pattern to match).  Just make them non-greedy `*?`:

```
\{\{A1\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\}\}
```

https://regex101.com/r/pK4gE7/1